# Affinity Designer: How to save embedded image?

Tags: affinity-designer, bitmap

*In Affinity Designer 1.6, how do I save an embedded image to disk?*

Of course I want the original resolution of the image, and - if possible - the original EXIF data.

[image: Screenshot of layers]

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is not yet available in Affinity Designer (currently v1.7). There has been a discussion on the Serif forum about exporting embedded files, though.

For now there is no way to save the original file. As a workaround you can use C**opy-and-Paste** or use **Export Persona** > **Export Options** to batch export multiple images.

[image: Affinity Designer Export-Persona]

Comment: I tried copy and paste, but I believe it only copies at the document resolution. I need the images at the original resolution.

Answer (score 1):

**A workaround, one image at a time**

Your images seem still be image objects, which is fortunate. They are not converted  to pixel layers, so there's still available the original full resolution image.

To export an image remove all possible effects and masks. Select the image, apply to it File > Export.

Select proper format for your purposes, let the export contain only the selected item and (important) set manually export size.

The export size can be selected at least for JPG, TIF and PNG exports. Export as PSD unfortunately contains only the low resolution version and it's flattened to a single layer image (see NOTE1).

An example:

[image]

The image object in my document was originally a 2560 pixels wide screenshot, but it is scaled to about 500 px wide which makes it unreadable. The original size is shown in the info line just below the Affinity designer logo. I have typed manually 2560 x 1440 to the size boxes in the export dialog.

After exporting and opening the result in another program I could verify the result was as sharp as the original and had pixel dimensions 2560 x 1440:

[image]

You wanted also to keep the possible original metadata made by camera and image editing software. I skip that subject due too poor knowledge.

NOTE1: The image object still can have all original resolution if you export it as PNG, TIF or JPG. But the original PSD layer structure is flattened.